# Uploading multiple images to Google Cloud Storage using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am no JavaScript expert, and I have managed to hack together a node.js script that does exactly what I want it to do: upload images contained within a folder to Google Cloud Storage for a Firebase project, and then return the public access URLs. Given that I have limited experience with node.js combined with GC Storage, please advise me on any issues that running this code over approximately 200 images in the folder may cause.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const projectId = 'XXXXXXX';

//Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: 'auth.json'
  });

// Reference the bucket
var bucket = storage.bucket('XXXXXXX.appspot.com');

//This reads the folder where the images are stored
fs.readdir('ImagesToUpload', (err, files) => {

    if( err ) {
        console.error( "Could not read the directory.", err );
        process.exit( 1 );
    } 

    files.forEach(function( file, index ) {

        var filePath = 'ImagesToUpload/'

        console.log(file)

        // Upload a local file to a new file to be created in the bucket
        bucket.upload(filePath += file, (err, file) => {
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            let publicUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${projectId}.appspot.com/o/${file.metadata.name}?alt=media`;
            console.log(publicUrl);
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. A few nits:

1. You might as well use `const` where you can, and `let` when that doesn't work. You can avoid `var` completely.
2. Instead of `var filePath = 'ImagesToUpload/'`-- and then modifying `filePath` with `+=`, just set `filePath` to the correct path immediately, ie. `const filePath = 'ImagesToUpload' + file`. This is just simpler and easier to read.
3. A subtler point: The logs are providing you your only reference to the file mapping onto the server. I'm concerned that these async functions won't necessarily run in order. Consider a huge file followed by a small file. Would the loop of files allow `bucket.upload` calls to be running at the same time? I would assume so. The small one would complete before the large one. If this happens, it's possible that your log `console.log(file)` will happen out of sequence with the `console.log(publicUrl)`. This can be solved by moving the first console `log` into the loop right before the `publicUrl` log.
4. Unused arguments at the end of the list can be omitted safely in JS, so `function( file, index )` can be simply `function( file)`, or even `file =>` if you use the new ES syntax (which you are)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the clear and concise answer!